# Couldn't find User with id=pJycxPPmoBQw9D2mfW6W

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorcery

Actually I'm using sorcery for authentification with the following set up :

- rails 3.2.3
- postgresql 9.1.3
- cancan

When I click on the activation link I get the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in UsersController#activate 

Couldn't find User with id=pJycxPPmoBQw9D2mfW6W
```

**users_controllers.rb**

#cancan

```
before_filter :require_login, :except => [:not_authenticated, :new, :create, :activate]
load_and_authorize_resource 
skip_authorization_check :only => [:new, :create, :activate]
skip_authorize_resource  :only => [:new, :create, :activate]
```

#activate method

```
def activate
    if (@user = User.load_from_activation_token(params[:id]))
      @user.activate!
      redirect_to(login_path, :notice => 'Your account is activated.')
    else
      not_authenticated
    end
  end
```

**generate token**

```
def generate_token(column)
    begin
      self[column] = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
    end while User.exists?(column => self[column])
end
```

**load_from_activation_token in sorcery source code**

```
def load_from_activation_token(token)
  token_attr_name = @sorcery_config.activation_token_attribute_name
  token_expiration_date_attr = @sorcery_config.activation_token_expires_at_attribute_name
  load_from_token(token, token_attr_name, token_expiration_date_attr)
end
```

Can I have some help please?

Comment: Apparently, you have error in `#activate`. But since we don't see its code, we can't help you.

Comment: Just added the #activate method

Comment: Add other relevant methods too.

Comment: Where's `User.load_from_activation_token`?

Comment: It's a sorcery method in the source code! I've added in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aha, I think the problem is here:

```
load_and_authorize_resource
```

Apparently, `params[:id]` for `#activate` request is not a user id, but a token. Cancan tries to load a user with this and (expectedly) fails. You need to skip loading for this action too (in a similar manner to how you already skip authorization).

```
skip_load_and_authorize_resource  :only => [:new, :create, :activate]
```